# Ubuntu hangs and becomes unresponsive until reset

Tags: kernel, crash

## Update Sep 8, 2022

I'm confident that the issue was with the BIOS. After it has been reflashed with an external programmer, I have seen no issues since. I'm *still not 100% sure* - only the time will show. It's mindblowing to think that hunting OS issues down takes *years*.

---

## Original description

I experience quite annoying behavior on my Ubuntu 20.04. Every few days, the system becomes suddenly unresponsive until I hit the reset button (raising elephants is so utterly boring also helps). And I cannot track the issue down. Here is the `/var/log/syslog` at the crash time:

```
Oct 19 13:09:31 ubu dbus-daemon[845]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.270' (ui
d=1000 pid=31899 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --enable-crashpad https:" 
label="snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community (complain)")
Oct 19 13:09:31 ubu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749845] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749849] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749869] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:467 dev_watchdog+0x24f/0x260
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749874] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype aufs xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bpfilter pktcdvd nvidia_uvm(POE) intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) kvm snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi rt2800usb snd_hda_intel rt2x00usb snd_intel_dspcfg rt2800lib soundwire_intel rt2x00lib soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec mac80211 snd_hda_core uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc soundwire_bus intel_cstate snd_usb_audio videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_soc_core snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hwdep snd_compress videobuf2_common ac97_bus videodev snd_pcm_dmaengine mc cfg80211 snd_pcm cp210x nvidia(POE) usbserial input_leds snd_seq_midi libarc4 joydev serio_raw i7core_edac snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749922]  snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd drm_kms_helper cec asus_atk0110 rc_core fb_sys_fops syscopyarea soundcore sysfillrect mac_hid sysimgblt sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid gpio_ich psmouse i2c_i801 i2c_smbus firewire_ohci firewire_core crc_itu_t r8169 lpc_ich realtek xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas ahci libahci
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749953] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: P          IOE     5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749956] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P7P55D-E, BIOS 1601    06/26/2012
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749957] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x24f/0x260
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749959] Code: 07 78 fd ff eb ab 4c 89 ff c6 05 b2 2d ee 00 01 e8 26 3c fa ff 44 89 e9 4c 89 fe 48 c7 c7 f8 3f 89 a6 48 89 c2 e8 4f 56 16 00 <0f> 0b eb 8c 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 66 90 66 66 66 66 90
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749961] RSP: 0018:ffffaa5280180e88 EFLAGS: 00010282
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749963] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9d1f826f0400 RCX: 0000000000000027
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749964] RDX: 0000000000000027 RSI: 00000000ffffdfff RDI: ffff9d2097a98ac8
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749965] RBP: ffffaa5280180eb8 R08: ffff9d2097a98ac0 R09: ffffaa5280180c48
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749966] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000001
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749967] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff9d1f8d80c4c0 R15: ffff9d1f8d80c000
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749968] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9d2097a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749970] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749971] CR2: 000002f600039040 CR3: 0000000145c10000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749973] Call Trace:
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749974]  <IRQ>
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749976]  ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x150/0x150
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749979]  call_timer_fn+0x2e/0x100
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749982]  __run_timers.part.0+0x1e0/0x250
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749985]  ? hpet_msi_interrupt_handler+0x1d/0x30
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749988]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749990]  __do_softirq+0xe0/0x29b
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749995]  asm_call_irq_on_stack+0x12/0x20
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749997]  </IRQ>
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.749998]  do_softirq_own_stack+0x3d/0x50
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750001]  irq_exit_rcu+0xa4/0xb0
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750004]  common_interrupt+0x7d/0x150
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750007]  asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750009] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xdc/0x350
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750012] Code: 66 90 31 ff e8 d5 b3 77 ff 80 7d d7 00 74 17 9c 58 66 66 90 66 90 f6 c4 02 0f 85 52 02 00 00 31 ff e8 68 5d 7e ff fb 66 66 90 <66> 66 90 45 85 ff 0f 88 e5 00 00 00 49 63 c7 4c 2b 75 c8 48 8d 14
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750013] RSP: 0018:ffffaa52800a7e48 EFLAGS: 00000246
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750015] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000004 RCX: 000000000000001f
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750016] RDX: ffff9d1f80134640 RSI: 0000000025f03b35 RDI: 0000000000000000
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750017] RBP: ffffaa52800a7e80 R08: 00000f2456d1678e R09: 0000000000000001
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750018] R10: ffff9d2097aaaee4 R11: ffff9d2097aaaec4 R12: ffff9d2097ab7100
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750019] R13: ffffffffa6c4d8e0 R14: 00000f2456d1678e R15: 0000000000000004
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750022]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xd8/0x350
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750024]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750026]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750028]  do_idle+0x1df/0x260
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750030]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750031]  start_secondary+0x11f/0x160
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750034]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
Oct 19 13:09:51 ubu kernel: [16648.750037] ---[ end trace 010da4fe0ea94408 ]---
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
<repeated>
```

There are some call traces but they don't make any sense to me.

The issue often occurs when I'm opening Chrome with Python+webbrowser module, though I'm not sure if that is the *only* reason. <strike>In particular, I recall that I had kernel crashes several times in other scenarios without Python involved.</strike> I don't trust my memory anymore, and I haven't noted it down. Comment deleted.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

---

Update 1.

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8146032     5994208      213836      256784     1937988     1610020
Swap:       4881404     1181440     3699964
```

---

Update 2.

```
$ ls -al /var/crash/
total 12
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 жов 15 18:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096 лип 22 10:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 kernoops whoopsie 2869 жов 15 18:14 linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic.209089.crash

$ cat /var/crash/linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic.209089.crash
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Fri Oct 15 18:14:19 2021
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [kworker/3:1:4185]
 Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype aufs xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bpfilter pktcdvd nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg rt2800usb soundwire_intel rt2x00usb soundwire_generic_allocation rt2800lib soundwire_cadence rt2x00lib kvm nvidia(POE) snd_hda_codec mac80211 intel_cstate snd_hda_core snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib soundwire_bus snd_hwdep snd_soc_core uvcvideo cfg80211 snd_compress serio_raw ac97_bus i7core_edac snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 libarc4 snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common snd_pcm joydev videodev input_leds snd_seq mc
  snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper cec rc_core fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt snd_timer snd soundcore asus_atk0110 mac_hid sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid gpio_ich firewire_ohci firewire_core psmouse i2c_i801 i2c_smbus lpc_ich crc_itu_t r8169 xhci_pci realtek ahci xhci_pci_renesas libahci
 CPU: 3 PID: 4185 Comm: kworker/3:1 Tainted: P      D W IOE     5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P7P55D-E, BIOS 1601    06/26/2012
 Workqueue: rcu_gp wait_rcu_exp_gp
 RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_single+0xa0/0x120
 Code: fc ab 7a a9 00 01 ff 00 0f 85 83 00 00 00 85 c9 75 42 48 c7 c6 40 d2 02 00 65 48 03 35 81 96 ab 7a 8b 46 08 a8 01 74 09 f3 90 <8b> 46 08 a8 01 75 f7 83 4e 08 01 4c 89 46 10 48 89 56 18 e8 b8 fe
 RSP: 0018:ffffb8d1c8803d60 EFLAGS: 00000202
 RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: ffffffff86b553f8 RCX: 0000000000000000
 RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff9fd457aed240 RDI: 0000000000000002
 RBP: ffffb8d1c8803db8 R08: ffffffff8552d5d0 R09: 0000000000000002
 R10: ffff9fd40de4fd2c R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 000000000000000a
 R13: 0000000000000004 R14: ffff9fd457aad080 R15: ffffffff86b55240
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9fd457ac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 0000385a095fb000 CR3: 000000010b0a0000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
 Call Trace:
 
Package: linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic 5.11.0-37.41~20.04.2
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 5.11.0-37-generic x86_64
```

This crash corresponds to the following lines in `/var/log/syslog`. I've uploaded the crash log [crash-Oct15.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wagyovx0jonlv9a/crash-Oct15.txt?dl=1)  to dropbox because it's too long - this time I got multiple kernel crashes happened at once one after the other.

---

Update 3.

I have another crash without the network driver involved. This time, I had peculiar behavior: I could move the mouse over the screen though I couldn't click it, and other peripherals didn't respond either.

```
Oct 20 12:12:45 ubu dbus-daemon[835]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requ
ested by ':1.294' (uid=1000 pid=73247 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome --enable-crashpad https:" label="snap.pycharm-community.pych
arm-community (complain)")
Oct 20 12:12:45 ubu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108050] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [chrome:73888]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108059] Modules linked in: btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs m
sdos jfs xfs cpuid nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype aufs xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_
reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf
_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink bpfilter pktcdvd nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_g
eneric ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cade
nce snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core soundwire_bus nvidia(POE) rt2800usb snd_soc_core rt2x00usb snd_usb_audio intel_powerclamp snd_compr
ess coretemp rt2800lib snd_usbmidi_lib ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi kvm_intel snd_seq_midi_event rt2x00lib sn
d_seq snd_rawmidi kvm mac80211 snd_pcm uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108111]  snd_seq_device serio_raw videobuf2_common i7core_edac videodev snd_timer mc cfg80211 s
nd drm_kms_helper libarc4 input_leds cec rc_core joydev fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore asus_atk0110 mac_h
id sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables msr parport_pc ppdev lp d
rm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid gpio_ich psmouse r8169 firewire_ohci realtek lpc_ich firewire_core i2
c_i801 ahci crc_itu_t i2c_smbus xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas libahci
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108147] CPU: 3 PID: 73888 Comm: chrome Tainted: P          IOE     5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.
2-Ubuntu
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108149] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P7P55D-E, BIOS 1601    06/26/201
2
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108151] RIP: 0010:_nv028953rm+0x2c/0x90 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108555] Code: ec 08 48 85 ff 74 5f 48 8b 57 10 31 c0 48 85 d2 74 2e 48 8b 4f 08 31 c0 48 85 c9 74 0d 48 63 41 14 48 89 d6 48 29 c6 48 89 f0 <48> 3b 57 18 48 89 07 74 1b 48 8b 42 08 48 89 47 10 b8 01 00 00 00
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108557] RSP: 0018:ffffad410b6cfb90 EFLAGS: 00000297
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108558] RAX: ffffef8a00c1e1be RBX: ffff9d583645b430 RCX: ffff9d588939f978
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108560] RDX: ffffef8a00c1d148 RSI: ffffef8a00c1e1be RDI: ffff9d57b08e5d20
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108561] RBP: ffff9d57b08e5d20 R08: 0000000000000020 R09: ffff9d57b08e5d28
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108562] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9d58a82eb798
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108563] R13: ffffef8a00051036 R14: ffff9d57b08e5d98 R15: ffff9d583645b430
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108564] FS:  00007f12c37d6540(0000) GS:ffff9d5997ac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108566] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108567] CR2: 00007fb4731dbf80 CR3: 00000001b0030000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108569] Call Trace:
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108572]  ? _nv035831rm+0xa8/0xe0 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.108897]  ? _nv014653rm+0x2ee/0x770 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.109223]  ? _nv037672rm+0xb3/0x150 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.109549]  ? _nv037671rm+0x297/0x4e0 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.109874]  ? _nv037666rm+0x60/0x70 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.110199]  ? _nv037667rm+0x7b/0xb0 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.110525]  ? _nv036043rm+0x40/0xe0 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.110774]  ? _nv000699rm+0x68/0x80 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111073]  ? rm_cleanup_file_private+0xea/0x160 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111372]  ? nvidia_close+0x15f/0x2e0 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111564]  ? security_file_free+0x54/0x60
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111570]  ? nvidia_frontend_close+0x2f/0x50 [nvidia]
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111767]  ? __fput+0x9f/0x250
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111771]  ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111773]  ? task_work_run+0x70/0xb0
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111776]  ? do_exit+0x389/0xaf0
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111779]  ? do_group_exit+0x43/0xa0
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111782]  ? __x64_sys_exit_group+0x18/0x20
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111784]  ? do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Oct 20 12:13:12 ubu kernel: [11688.111786]  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Oct 20 12:13:18 ubu kernel: [11693.732644] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Oct 20 12:13:18 ubu gnome-shell[3765]: [1020/121318.631417:WARNING:exception_snapshot_linux.cc(427)] Unhandled signal -1
Oct 20 12:13:18 ubu gnome-shell[3765]: [1020/121318.631782:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Oct 20 12:13:18 ubu gnome-shell[3765]: [1020/121318.631807:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
Oct 20 12:13:19 ubu kernel: [11694.196698] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Oct 20 12:13:19 ubu kernel: [11694.908690] sysrq: This sysrq operation is disabled.
Oct 20 12:13:20 ubu kernel: [11695.228730] sysrq: Emergency Sync
Oct 20 12:13:20 ubu kernel: [11695.338249] Emergency Sync complete
Oct 20 12:13:20 ubu kernel: [11695.636742] sysrq: Emergency Remount R/O
```

---

Update 4 (Nov 06, 2021)

I had another crash today. I've uploaded the log on Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsceadfvqie2rjs/crash-Nov16.log?dl=1

Seems like I'm getting this kind of crash only when I open a Chrome via Python `webbrowser` package (but not immediately and sometimes without a problem).

---

Update 5

I have Nvidia GTX 980, driver 470.42.01.

The BIOS version is P7P55D-E BIOS 1601, the latest available from the manufacturer (2013 year).

---

Update 6

I've hit another crash of the same type while running a Python program (opening a browser with the `webbrowser` library). I've updated every PC component save for two SSDs that I've left unchanged.

Syslog file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz2331idgyt7un0/crash-Jan22.txt?dl=1

---

Update 7.

Had another crash today. This time I was opening a link in a Chrome browser from a telegram. No Python involved. No `webbrowser` Python lib respectively.

Syslog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2ug91s3kalce04/crash_Jan29.txt?dl=1

Comment: How much RAM, how much swap? Use `free` to see. Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I edited the question and added the info you requested.

Comment: Assuming you've had this problem more than once, do the crash logs always start with "NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0 (r8169)" like this one? Show me `ls -al /var/crash` (as an edit to your question, not into the comments please). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @waltinator A portion of your comment... *"Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you"* is incorrect. Comments are for **bidirectional** communication between the OP and users who have left other comments... not only **our uplink to you**.

Comment: @heynnema I added the content of the only file in the `/var/crash` directory. Thanks, I didn't about the existence of this folder.

Comment: @heynnema I have one more similar entry in one of the older `/var/log/syslog.x` with "NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0" string before the kernel crash. It's dated Oct 15 and corresponds to the `/var/crash/linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic.209089.crash` that I also included in the question. However, it's not the only case when the kernel crashes. I added another log that happened an hour ago without the NETDEV mentioned.

Comment: **It's your Nvidia. What model Nvidia. What version driver? Your BIOS is also outdated.**

Comment: @heynnema I've added the graphics card info.

Comment: Nvidia software version 495.44 can be downloaded from https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/. You're correct, your BIOS is current. Report back.

Comment: I've updated Nvidia driver to the latest 495. I'll let you know if this doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema hi, it's been a long time. I've experienced the problem again several times. I updated the PC recently but still see the issue. I added the description. I do think it's an issue in Python selenium package.

Comment: @dizcza What version selenium?

Comment: @heynnema selenium v4.0.0. I've already updated this several times, it doesn't help.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, it's not selenium but Python built-in webbrowser package that I call `webbrowser.get('google-chrome')`. Shall I fire an issue on the official Python issue tracker page?

Comment: @dizcza The latest selenium is version 4.1.0 or 4.1.1, depending on where I look. Try it. Otherwise feel free to log an issue on the official Python tracker page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a very old computer, but I suspect that this might fix your problem, based on the information provided in your question...

MSI/MSIX interrupts were enabled for certain ethernet cards in Ubuntu 20.xx. This can cause intermittent ethernet operation. Here's a patch to fix it. Follow the embedded instructions to install.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779817

# filename: r8169_disable_msi

# Drop it in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top and chmod a+x it. Add 'r8169_disable_msi'
# to your kernel command line (/etc/default/grub, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
# usually.) 

# sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub # to edit the file

# Remember to update-initramfs and update-grub as necessary.

# sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
# sudo update-grub
# reboot

# For the moment it disables MSI on everything with the ID 0x10ec:0x8168, as there seems to
# be no way to get the MAC version from userspace - and certainly not before the driver is
# loaded. Other PCI IDs may need adding..

PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}
case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

disable_msi () {
    for i in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*; do 
        if [ $(cat $i/vendor) = "0x10ec" -a $(cat $i/device) = "0x8168" ]; then
            echo 0 >$i/msi_bus
        fi
    done
}

for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
        case ${x} in
        r8169_disable_msi)
        disable_msi
        break
                ;;
        esac
done
```

**Update #1:**

OP reset the BIOS, and removed CPU overclocking, and so far, it's run for 6 days without difficulty. It may take a little more time to confirm it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested fix, I'll try it. I've appended `r8169_disable_msi` to the default command line so now it's `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash r8169_disable_msi"`. I did the rest of the steps and let you know if the issue still persists.

Comment: And yeah, my motherboard and CPU are old, and the CPU does not support AVX2 instructions, which became problematic only this year when I found out that some software requires AVX2 instructions support as a must-have. Apart from this, I've overclocked the CPU frequency to some extent and have not changed it for years, and it worked fine. It's sad that I must think of renovating the otherwise completely fine and fast working machine.

Comment: @dizcza Remove fsck.mode=skip. Set your CPU clock back to default (not overclocked) and see if things improve. Report back.

Comment: I reset BIOS and `/etc/default/grub` to defaults. It will take a week to test if things are improved. I'll let you know.

Comment: @dizcza Status please...

Comment: @dizcza I just noticed your last crash edit. Nvidia was involved. What model Nvidia? What version driver? Where did you get the driver from?

Comment: well, I had no crashes for the last 6 days since I reset BIOS to defaults. The NVIDIA card I'm using is GTX 980. Driver 470.42.01, the latest (or almost so). The driver and its automatic updates were set up by downloading an executable package file from the nvidia developer official website alongside the cuda toolkit.

Comment: Not to be confused, being unable to edit the comment above, here is the phrase I wanted  to say: The driver and its automatic updates were set up by installing a cuda toolkit package from the nvidia developer official website.

Comment: @dizcza So, just to be clear, you reset the BIOS, which removed the overclocking on the CPU, and it's worked fine for 6 days? Correct?

Comment: Correct. The overclocked CPU seems to start leaking juice. A late retirement for an old champ.

Comment: It's hard to believe though that it was the *only* issue. And I remember running it last months without a problem two weeks straight. Perhaps, overclocking was the catalyst, not the culprit. Anyway, thanks for your help. I was biased not to look in a thing that has been working for years - overclocking. If you post your comment about turning off overclocking and resetting BIOS to defaults, I'll mark it as an answer. I'll drop a comment if crashes start occurring again.

Comment: @dizcza Edit done. Thanks!

Comment: hi, I had another crash today. I've updated the question. Should I open an issue in Python webdriver module?

Comment: I've also noticed that each crash is followed by the `Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped` log. I don't have a Bluetooth peripheral on my PC. Perhaps, it's just a check that is executed before another check that always fails.

Comment: @dizcza See my comment, above.