# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS freezes, requiring a hard reboot

Tags: freeze

I am experiencing regular system freezes running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H with NV168 graphics card.

The computer does not respond to ctrl-alt-F1 and the only way out seems to be a hard reset.

I have two examples of syslog from the crashes. These would have been the most recent freezes, but it has already frozen once more whilst composing this question.

Please advise how I might fix this problem, and understand I am a bit of n00b with this stuff. Thanks for your patience. Please also let me know if I can provide any other information that will help with resolving this. I think it may be related to this issue which has similar output in the logs but, what do i know? I await the help of the experts.
[Ubuntu hangs and becomes unresponsive until reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370213/ubuntu-hangs-and-becomes-unresponsive-until-reset)

Edit:
Info requested by @heynnema:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Aug 19 11:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Aug 19 11:47 ..
```

Edit2:
here are the outputs of the two commands you asked me to run, @heynnema. Not sure why it can't find the first one - is there another command I can try?

```
ronan@ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/ronan/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
ronan@ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug 19 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 19 11:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 12 23:54 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 19 11:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 19 11:35 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Edit 3:

```
ronan@ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H:~$ ls -al /etc/X11
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 134 root root 12288 Dec 16 12:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:41 app-defaults
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:40 cursors
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    15 Aug 19 11:42 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:39 fonts
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 17394 Jan 20  2017 rgb.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:40 xinit
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 29  2020 xkb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   709 Jan 20  2017 Xreset
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:40 Xreset.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:40 Xresources
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3730 Dec 14  2018 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:41 Xsession.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   265 Jan 20  2017 Xsession.options
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:41 xsm
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    13 Feb 29  2020 XvMCConfig
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   630 Aug 19 11:41 Xwrapper.config
ronan@ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
```

Syslog 1:

```
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 14: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0xd0b0b) [0x7fa20b7ad6fb]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 15: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (nouveau_drm_screen_create+0xd2271) [0x7fa20b7aee61]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 16: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so (__driDriverGetExtensions_d3d12+0x158981) [0x7fa20aec68c1]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 17: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_create_gc+0x903d) [0x7fa20c73a17d]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 18: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_create_gc+0xa62a) [0x7fa20c73b76a]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 19: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DamageRegionAppend+0x6c0) [0x557697e91870]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (CompositeRegisterImplicitRedirectionException+0x15eb) [0x557697e39fab]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 21: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (CompositeRegisterImplicitRedirectionException+0x1450) [0x557697e39e10]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 22: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (CompositeRegisterImplicitRedirectionException+0x1450) [0x557697e39e10]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 23: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (compIsAlternateVisual+0x708) [0x557697e3aeb8]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 24: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (compIsAlternateVisual+0xbc3) [0x557697e3b373]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 25: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (ProcessWorkQueue+0x36) [0x557697db3ec6]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 26: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0xc2) [0x557697f0a232]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 27: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x117) [0x557697daed77]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 28: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3b4) [0x557697db3064]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 29: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7fa20cda90b3]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) 30: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2e) [0x557697d9caae]
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE)
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE)
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: Fatal server error:
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE)
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE)
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]:  for help.
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/ronan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Dec 15 13:31:14 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[988]: (EE)
Dec 15 13:31:16 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2600]: [12/15/21, 13:31:16:911] info: [API-Q] (T21C2SH61) noversion-1639575076.911 Flannel users/info called with reason: flannel-call:users/info
Dec 15 13:31:16 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2600]: [12/15/21, 13:31:16:911] info: [API-Q] (T21C2SH61) noversion-1639575076.911 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Dec 15 13:31:16 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2600]: [12/15/21, 13:31:16:911] info: [API-Q] (T21C2SH61) noversion-1639575076.911 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Dec 15 13:31:16 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2600]: [12/15/21, 13:31:16:930] info: [API-Q] (T21C2SH61) noversion-1639575076.911 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Dec 15 13:31:17 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H systemd[963]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded.
Dec 15 13:31:37 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Dec 15 13:31:39 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2624]: [1215/133139.029470:WARNING:exception_snapshot_linux.cc(427)] Unhandled signal -1
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Dec 15 13:32:34 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H systemd-modules-load[358]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

Second Syslog:

````
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1900.010376] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1900.010379] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010375] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010377] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010391] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 3610 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/fifo/gk104.c:447 gk104_fifo_recover_engn+0x210/0x220 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010442] Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_sof snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel kvm soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep aesni_intel soundwire_bus crypto_simd cryptd snd_soc_core glue_helper nouveau snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine iwlmvm snd_pcm snd_seq_midi rapl snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi uvcvideo mxm_wmi drm_ttm_helper videobuf2_vmalloc mac80211 intel_cstate ttm btusb videobuf2_memops libarc4 snd_seq btrtl videobuf2_v4l2 drm_kms_helper btbcm videobuf2_common btintel snd_seq_device cec
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010472]  snd_timer bluetooth iwlwifi videodev rc_core serio_raw i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops efi_pstore intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof joydev input_leds ee1004 mc snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ecdh_generic sysimgblt cfg80211 ecc ucsi_ccg hid_multitouch processor_thermal_device mei_me soundcore processor_thermal_rfim mei processor_thermal_mbox processor_thermal_rapl intel_rapl_common ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal typec ideapad_laptop mac_hid sparse_keymap int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul nvme i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci r8169 rtsx_pci i2c_smbus intel_lpss ahci nvme_core realtek idma64 libahci virt_dma i2c_nvidia_gpu i2c_hid xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas hid wmi pinctrl_cannonlake video
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010506] CPU: 10 PID: 3610 Comm: kworker/10:2 Not tainted 5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010507] Hardware name: LENOVO 81Y8/LNVNB161216, BIOS EFCN39WW 08/03/2020
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010508] Workqueue: events nvkm_notify_work [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010533] RIP: 0010:gk104_fifo_recover_engn+0x210/0x220 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010574] Code: 78 10 48 8b 57 50 48 85 d2 75 03 48 8b 17 48 89 55 80 e8 d3 06 d5 f2 48 8b 55 80 48 c7 c7 ea a0 f3 c0 48 89 c6 e8 06 74 14 f3 <0f> 0b e9 47 ff ff ff e8 a4 17 1a f3 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010575] RSP: 0018:ffffa5f54352bc18 EFLAGS: 00010086
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010576] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff90c2089bd000 RCX: 0000000000000027
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010577] RDX: 0000000000000027 RSI: 00000000ffffdfff RDI: ffff90c54dc98ac8
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010578] RBP: ffffa5f54352bc98 R08: ffff90c54dc98ac0 R09: ffffa5f54352b9d8
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010578] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000000
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010579] R13: 0000000000002a30 R14: ffff90c209476c00 R15: 0000000000000040
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010580] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90c54dc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010581] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010582] CR2: 0000308709a93000 CR3: 00000001bb810006 CR4: 00000000007706e0
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010583] PKRU: 55555554
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010583] Call Trace:
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010585]  gk104_fifo_recover_chan+0x1be/0x280 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010625]  gk104_fifo_fault+0x11a/0x2b0 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010662]  nvkm_fifo_fault+0x15/0x20 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010699]  gv100_fault_ntfy_nrpfb+0x1e7/0x230 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010728]  nvkm_notify_work+0x22/0x80 [nouveau]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010750]  process_one_work+0x220/0x3c0
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010752]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010753]  ? process_one_work+0x3c0/0x3c0
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010754]  kthread+0x12b/0x150
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010756]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x40/0x40
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010758]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010760] ---[ end trace 85197d926947b53a ]---
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010762] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010801] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000001 FAULT at 00259c [ TIMEOUT ]
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.010913] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: systemd-logind[812]: channel 2 killed!
Dec 15 14:04:07 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H kernel: [ 1902.016072] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 00000001 FAULT at 00262c [ TIMEOUT ]
Dec 15 14:04:09 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2722]: [12/15/21, 14:04:09:063] info: [RTM] (T21C2SH61) Processed 1 user_typing event(s) in channel(s) C21C4GEDV over 23.60ms
Dec 15 14:04:12 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2722]: [12/15/21, 14:04:12:725] info: [RTM] (T21C2SH61) Processed 1 user_typing event(s) in channel(s) C21C4GEDV over 0.10ms
Dec 15 14:04:15 ronan-Lenovo-Legion-5-17IMH05H slack.desktop[2722]: [12/15/21, 14:04:15:802] info: [RTM] (T21C2SH61) Processed 1 user_typing event(s) in channel(s) C21C4GEDV over 0.10ms```
````

Comment: I updated the BIOS with the latest firmware from Lenovo's website but the crash happened again shortly after that.

Comment: I have had a number of further freezes, but have maxed out how long i can make the question. Please let me know if these logs will be helpful. thanks

Comment: Did you use the efcn52ww bios update, or something else? Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema yes, that was the bios update!

Comment: @heynnema I will try the memtest, thanks

Comment: @heynnema my computer has passed the memtest with no errors.

Comment: Good job! Do you have an Nvidia video card? If so, are Nvidia drivers installed, and if so, what version? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: @heynnema, Yes, I have an Nvidia card. I checked the drivers and they were set to X.Org so I have updated to nvidia-driver-470.

Comment: @heynnema, i have added to results of "ls -al /var/crash" to the end of the question.

Comment: @heynnema, please excuse the formatting, for some reason it won't display them with the line breaks

Comment: Regarding the formatting... after pasting in structured text, select that text, then click the {} icon to format it into human-readable text.

Comment: Good job on installing Nvidia 470. Edit your question again and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Looks like the Xorg server is crashing, as I see in Syslog 1.

Comment: Looks like Something is wrong! Xorg server recently got a major security upgrade, so maybe running `sudo apt upgrade` will also help! You may want to try using some other DE to see if the error is still there. (_Of course, don't install a whole new DE for just testing, If you can then only do this heavy experiment_).

Comment: @someone Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @heynnema I'm happy to help! Also, the output of `cat home/ronan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` would be helpful. Take your time.

Comment: @heynnema I was able to use the computer for a few hours today without the freeze occurring, since updating to Nvidia's latest drivers. Usually it freezes within fifteen minutes or so. Touch wood, this issue is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @skypotatoes We're not done yet. Things may be improving, but we have a few more things to check. See my comment from 13 minutes ago.

Comment: That is great! @skypotatoes I agree with heynnema's comment.

Comment: @someone I will get the output for you as soon as I can. I'm out at the moment.

Comment: @skypotatoes Also show me `ls -al /etc/X11` and `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: @someone Always best to do `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt upgrade`. Good idea though. Also your Xorg.0.log command should start with /home... or better yet... `more ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`. :-)

Comment: @heynnema , I added the output of two commands you asked me to try, but it can't find the first of the files you asked for. The same thing happened when I ran the "cat home/ronan/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" requested by someone. Am I inputting something wrong?

Comment: I ran more `more ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` and the output is huge, I don't know if it will fit into the question.

Comment: @skypotatoes  Your gnome-shell extensions look fine. Don't worry about the Xorg.0.log file for now. Continue to test after the Nvidia 470 driver install, which sounds like it fixed things for now. Please see my summary answer, and please accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema, many thanks to you for your help, machine seems to be running fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Lenovo Legion 5 17IMH05H with Nvidia NV168 graphics card.

**Note**: X server was crashing with nouveau.

**Note**: `memtest` ran fine.

**Note**: BIOS updated to efcn52ww.

Updated to Nvidia driver 470 and so far it's running fine.

Also do:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`